# Can't import a local pg_dump in Heroku using Dropbox as url

Tags: postgresql, heroku

## Problem

I am following [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export) article from Heroku regarding a database migration (import). I created the database dump like in the example with `PGPASSWORD=mypassword pg_dump -Fc --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U myuser mydb > mydb.dump` and then tried to upload it with this command after creating a public accessible file via dropbox:

```
heroku pg:backups:restore 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/2hjbz9573oodmpp/my_new_db.dump?dl=1' DATABASE_URL -a my-app
```

This produces this error:

```
 ▸    An error occurred and the backup did not finish.
 ▸    
 ▸    pg_restore: error: could not read from input file: end of file
 ▸    pg_restore finished with errors
 ▸    waiting for download to complete
 ▸    download finished with errors
 ▸    please check the source URL and ensure it is publicly accessible
```

## Thoughts

It seems like the problem that the url is not publicy accessible. But I tried to open the url in the browser and it directly opens a download prompt. So is there anything I am not seeing? Is the only option using a signed url from AWS?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `?dl=1` from the url